# Finding the number of two digit numbers

Tags: diophantine-equations

I was solving questions from a book and it had a question :

> Find all two digit numbers such that the sum of digits constituting the number is not less than 7; the sum of squares of digits is not greater than 30; the number written in reverse order is not larger than half the numbers ".

I proceeded like this:
Let the no be $10x+y$.
So from the questions we have :

$$x+y \ge 7 \tag{1}$$
$$x^2 + y^2 \le 30\tag{2}$$
$$10y+x \le \frac{1}{2}(10x+y)\tag{3}$$

where $x \in [1,9]$ and $y\in[0,9]$. Now I am stuck up. How to proceed now?

Comment: Note that $o \le x,y. $ Plot the region which can satisfied by inequalities.

Comment: The first two conditions are highly restrictive. For example, we cannot have either digit greater than 5. You will find there are only a handful of numbers satisfying the first two conditions. Then check if they satisfy the third.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
7^{2} \leq x^{2} + 2xy + y^{2}\leq 30 + 2xy\quad\imp\quad -2xy\leq -19
$$

> $$
> \pars{x - y}^{2} = x^{2} - 2xy + y^{2}\leq 30 + \pars{-19} = 11\quad\imp\quad
> -\root{11} \leq x - y \leq \root{11} 
> $$

$$-3\leq x - y\leq 3$$

> $$
> \pars{~x + y \geq 7\quad\mbox{and}\quad x - y\geq -3~}\quad\imp\quad x \geq 2
> $$
>   $$
> \pars{~x + y \geq 7\quad\mbox{and}\quad y - x\geq -3~}\quad\imp\quad
> \color{#66f}{\Large y \geq 2}
> $$

Also,
$\quad\ds{x \geq {19 \over 8}\,y\geq {19 \over 4}\quad\imp\quad
\color{#66f}{\Large x\geq 5}.\quad}$

Also,
$\ds{30 \geq x^{2} + y^{2}\geq 25 + y^{2}\ \imp\
\color{#66f}{\Large \verts{y} \leq \root{5}}}$
.Then $\color{#66f}{\Large \ds{y = 2}}$.

> Similarly $\ds{30 \leq x^{2} + 2^2\quad\imp\quad \verts{x}\leq\root{26}\quad\imp
> \quad \color{#66f}{\Large x = 5}}$

There is just one solution: $\ds{\color{#c00000}{\LARGE 52}}$.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb R^2$, the first and third conditions define half planes, and the second one defines a disk. Draw these on gridded paper and you'll find the integer solutions in the intersection area.

Alternatively, try all two digit numbers by hand (using @almagest hint) or with a script.

```
for x in range(1, 9 + 1):
    for y in range(9 + 1):
        if x+y >= 7 and x*x+y*y <= 30 and 10*y+x <= (10*x+y)/2:
            print x, y
```

Output:

```
5 2
```

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$1\le x\le 9,\ \ 0\le y\le 9,\ \ x+y\ge 7,\ \ x^2+y^2\le 30,\ \ 10y+x\le\frac{10x+y}{2}\tag1$$

If we suppose that $x\ge 4\ \text{and}\ y\ge 4$, we have, from the fourth condition,
$$32=4^2+4^2\le x^2+y^2\le 30,$$
which is a contradiction. Hence, we have $x\le 3\ \text{or}\ y\le 3$.

Now you can separate it into cases as

Case 1 : Check if there is $y$ which satisfies $(1)$ for each of $x=1,2,3$.

Case 2 : Check if there is $x$ which satisfies $(1)$ for each of $y=0,1,2,3$.

So, we have $7$ cases to check.

**P.S.** Another way which needs only $6$ cases to check.

If we suppose $y\ge 6$, we have, from the fourth condition,
$$37=1^2+6^2\le x^2+y^2\le 30,$$
which is a contradiction. Hence, we have $y\le 5$.

So, you can check if there is $x$ which satisfies $(1)$ for each of $y=0,1,2,3,4,5$.

Answer (score 0):

$$x+y\ge 7 \tag{1}$$
$$x^2+y^2 \le 30 \tag{2}$$
$$ 10y+x \le \frac{1}{2}(10x+y) \tag{3}$$
$$\implies 20y+2x \le 10x+y $$
$$\implies 19y-8x\le0$$
$$\implies x \ge \frac{19y}{8}$$
$$\implies x \ge 2.35 y$$

Obviously, $x$ cannot be a decimal number, so you need to ceil $x$ to the upper value.

So, possible values for $x$ and  $y$ are: $(3,1),(5,2),(8,3)$

The only value that satisfy inequality $(1)$ and $(2)$ is $(5,2)$